# Atualizando conteúdo dentro de uma Lightbox sem dar Refresh na pagina

Tags: jquery, ajax

Bom galera, eu to usando o Lightbox e Ajax pra ampliação de conteúdo. O conteúdo propriamente dito sempre vem acompanhando de uma imagem, assim é só clicar nessa imagem que ela amplia e aparece o texto referente aquela imagem, como se fosse o Lightbox do Facebook. Bom assim que o conteúdo é ampliado também tem aquelas setas pra poder visualizar a postagem anterior ou a seguinte. O problema está ai, suponhamos que eu role metade da pagina pra baixo e clico em um conteúdo que achei interessante ai desejo abrir, apos eu clicar em próximo ou anterior a pagina volta ao topo, agora se eu clicar em um conteúdo qualquer, fechar o Lightbox e clicar em outro conteúdo ela não volta ao topo.

Quero que de pra clicar em próximo ou anterior sem que volte ao topo. Já tentei algumas coisas e nada deu certo.

Script do LightBox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.lightbox').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.background, .box').animate({'opacity':'.8'}, 0);
      $('.box').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 0);
      $('.background, .box').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('.close').click(function(){
    $('.background, .box').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 0, function(){
    $('.background, .box').css('display', 'none');
        });          
    });
    $('.background').click(function(){          
    $('.background, .box').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 0, function(){              
    $('.background, .box').css('display', 'none');              
        });          
    });      
});

</script>
```

Script do carregamento Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function GetXMLHttp() {
  if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
  xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  else {
  xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  return xmlHttp;
  }

  var xmlRequest = GetXMLHttp();

  function abrirPag(valor){
  var url = valor;

  xmlRequest.open("GET",url,true);
  xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = mudancaEstado;
  xmlRequest.send(null);

  if (xmlRequest.readyState == 1) {
  document.getElementById("conteudo_mostrar").innerHTML = "<img src='loader.gif'>";
  }

  return url;
  }

  function mudancaEstado(){
  if (xmlRequest.readyState == 4){
  document.getElementById("conteudo_mostrar").innerHTML = xmlRequest.responseText;
  }
  }
  </script>
```

Ambos os scripts sao acionados com o link:

```
<a class="lightbox" href="#" onclick="abrirPag('midia.php?I_POST=<?php echo $posts['ID'] ?>');">
```

A pagina midia.php faz parte do carregamento Ajax, nela eu pego por meio GET o id da postagem e carrego as informações referente a ela

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo do seu html? onde está o `conteudo_mostrar`? de qq maneira você vai ter de parar esse link com um return false ou preventDefault. Já agora, você controla o PHP? podia passar esse ID para um `data-id` , seria mais limpo a meu ver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tua página está a "voltar ao topo" porque quando clicas em:

```html
<a class="lightbox" href="#" onclick="abrirPag('midia.php?I_POST=1');">
```

Tens um `#` no atributo `href` que por defeito vai-te adicionar esse mesmo `#` no endereço da página no teu navegador, dando origem ao "voltar ao topo". Isto é um comportamento padrão dos navegadores porque efectivamente o `#` é conhecido por identificador de fragmento e utilizado para permitir *scroll* automático para uma localização especifica da página.

## Cancelar o identificador de fragmento

A solução passa por evitar que esse comportamento padrão do clique seja realizado, sendo a forma mais simples a adição de um `!` após o `#` no atributo `href`:

```html
<a class="lightbox" href="#!" onclick="abrirPag('midia.php?I_POST=1');">
```

<sup>Como o identificador de fragmento é suposto conter após o mesmo um valor correspondente a um `ID` na página e como não existem elementos com um `ID` exactamente igual a `!`, o *scroll* não é realizado pelo navegador.</sup>

## Usando JavaScript

Também podes adicionar no atributo `onclick` o cancelamento do comportamento padrão do identificador de fragmento `#` fazendo uso do `return false;`:

```html
<a class="lightbox" href="#" onclick="abrirPag('midia.php?I_POST=1'); return false;">
```

<sup>Em JavaScript, o `return false` é utilizado para evitar que o restante código seja executado. Quando aplicado após a chamada de uma função dentro do atributo `onclick`, ele vai evitar que o navegador continue a reagir ao clique ficando assim cancelando a leitura do atributo `href`.</sup>